# ¿Qué es una respuesta aceptable?

Tags: discusión, faq, respuesta

Adaptación de la pregunta [What is an acceptable answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118582/182862)

---

Respondí una pregunta y mi respuesta fue (elige una)

- eliminada
- convertida en comentario
- agregada a mi pregunta como una edición

¿Por qué pasó? ¿Por qué mi respuesta no fue aceptable?

**¿Cuál es la definición de una respuesta aceptable en Stack Exchange?**

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Respuesta adaptada de https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118694/182862

---

La siguiente es una ligera modificación de [la publicación de Lorem Ipsum en meta.gardening](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201/when-should-i-post-an-answer-and-when-should-i-post-a-comment/202#202). Considerar una pregunta de ejemplo:

> ### ¿Cómo puedo hacer foo para bar en X?
>
> Estoy intentando de hacer foo para bar usando Y. Sin embargo, obtengo el mensaje de error `<error>`. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

#### ¿Cuándo debería publicar un comentario y cuándo una respuesta?

```
Si tu respuesta es:      entonces sería:    Acción correctiva       Reportar como NeuR1

 1 ¿Puedes publicar      comentar en la     Si escribiste una          Sí
   tu código?            pregunta           respuesta, elimínala 
                                            y en su lugar comenta. 
                                            Si todavía no tienes
                                            50 de rep, por favor
                                            espera a alcanzarlos.

 2 ¿Hiciste foo                 "                    "                 Sí
   con M?

 3 ¿Qué versión de              "                    "                 Sí
   X usas?                 

 4 Tuve el mismo                "                    "                 Sí
   problema desde 
   la versión M.1

 5 Olvidaste una coma,          "           Marca la pregunta          No
   lo cual ocasiona                         como "Problema que
   el error.                                no se puede reproducir
                                            o un error tipográfico."

 6 Esto se revisó en            "           Votar a cierre como        Sí
   esta pregunta y su                       duplicado.
   respuesta [enlace
   interno de SOes]

 7 La respuesta          comentar en la     Escribir una respuesta     Sí
   aceptada no es        respuesta          mejor o avisar a quien 
   correcta o ya no                         respondió.
   lo es.

 8 No puedes hacer eso   una respuesta      Si es posible, vincular    No
   en X porque Y no lo                      la documentación.
   soporta.

 9 Esto es lo que está         "                    "                  No
   mal. [Explicar].
   Así es como debería
   hacerse [código]

10 Intenta esto:              "             Mejorar la respuesta.      No
   [código]                                 Explicar por qué esa es
                                            la solución. Si es
                                            una respuesta de solo
                                            código, usa comentarios
                                            para explicarlo.

11 Este es el problema:       "             Si es un enlace externo,   No
   [Explicar]. En una                       ayuda a documentar los 
   respuesta/entrada de                     puntos clave aquí, así 
   blog, yo/ellos                           la esencia del post está
   hablan de blah                           disponible incluso si el 
   [enlace] que puede                       enlace se quiebra. Hazlo 
   ser de interés                           tú mismo o deja un
                                            comentario para el OP.

12 Mira aquí:            necesita muchas    La respuesta debe ser      Depende
   [enlace externo]      mejoras            mejorada como se describe 
                                            arriba, sino será borrada. 
                                            Votar en contra si el enlace es
                                            tangencial a la pregunta. 
                                            Escribir una nueva respuesta
                                            detallada y luego reportar como NeuR.
                                            También reportar si el enlace 
                                            está roto.

13 Intenté estas        una nueva pregunta  Si tienes +75 de rep,      Sí
   soluciones y no                          considera poner una recompensa
   funciona en                              para buscar una mejor respuesta.
   [sistema operativo].                     Si no (o si es muy
   ¿Cómo debería cambiar                    distinto), inicia una nueva
   la solución para que                     pregunta.
   funcione?

14 ¡Gracias,            eliminado           Genial si funciona, pero   Sí
    funciona!!1!                            en serio, solo vota a favor 
                                            si tienes suficiente rep.

15 Tengo un proyecto    eliminado con       No alientes a estos        Sí
   similar que es       prejuicio           usuarios a publicar - 
   para mañana.          extremo            preguntas - es muy probable
   ¿Podriás enviarme                        que sean cerradas.
   el código a [correo]?

1NeuR: No es una Respuesta
```

#### ¿Por qué debería ser así?

Las primeras tres respuestas claramente están preguntando por más información y no responden la pregunta. La #4 es meramente una oración tipo "yo también" - no agrega valor. Si el único problema con el código es torpeza del OP o si es un duplicado (#5 o #6), entonces deberían ser cerrados como "error tipográfico" o "duplicado" respectivamente. Si es el primero de estos, la pregunta podría ser eliminada (ya sea por un moderador o por usuarios con 3k+ de rep). Mientras que la #7 ayuda, no responde la *pregunta*. Es una buena práctica dejar que el OP sepa que las cosas han cambiado. Si ellos no responden, votar en contra y seguir adelante o escribir una mejor respuesta, si es que puedes.

Las respuestas #8, #9 y #11 son lo que esperamos ver en este sitio. Son concisas, precisas e informativas. Si haces referencias a una respuesta anterior (puede ser también un enlace externo), provee un resumen crucial de manera que la respuesta sea auto contenida. Esto es importante por dos razones: tener el resumen ayuda en caso que el enlace se quiebra (p.e. los enlaces externos se quiebran porque el sitio al que pertenecen es dado de baja) y para que la gente no clickee por varios enlaces para obtener su respuesta. Ellos pueden proceder si les gusta lo que ven. Siempre ayuda enlazar a la documentación relevante/fuentes con autoridad (citando la información importante) en tus respuestas. Recuerda, en todos estos casos, deberías citar la(s) fuente(s) de tus citas (es una buena práctica hacerlo explícito en lugar de atribuirlo personalmente). Siéntete libre de editar estos enlaces en una respuesta (que no sea tuya) si el OP no lo ha hecho. Después de todo, este es un sitio de ediciones colaborativas.

Las respuestas #10 y #12 son bruscas y quizás las más contradictorias de todas. Resultan algo capciosas puesto que responden la pregunta pero no como se considerarían una buena respuesta. Los moderadores y usuarios frecuentes generalmente tratan de alentar a estos usuarios a expandir sus respuestas o citar las partes relevantes [del enlace]. Es cierto, dejar un enlace e irse como en la #12 es tentador. Sin embargo, recuerda que las respuestas que dejas no son solo para el OP, sino prácticamente para cualquiera que visita esa página. Si no tienes la voluntad de hacerlo, entonces es una buena idea no publicar ese enlace. La #10, técnicamente es una solución a la pregunta, pero no indica ni explica *por qué*. Adicionalmente, no se puede hacer más que esperar que los votos hablen por ella. Sin embargo, si la reportas como "No es una respuesta", mejor te preparas para una derrota. La única ocasión aceptable para notificarlas a la atención de un moderador es si el enlace está roto y no hay nada que indique qué pudo haber estado allí.

Las respuestas #13 a #15 son auto explicativas, pero por favor, no alientes a los usuarios que publicaron la #15 a formular preguntas aquí.

#### ¿Por qué convirtieron mi respuesta en un comentario y por qué me alentaron a publicar mi comentario como respuesta?

Usualmente cuando tus respuestas están en el rango entre #1 y #7, ellas no responden la pregunta y los moderadores la convierten en comentario, donde pertenecen (hasta que el OP responde/actualiza su pregunta). A veces, cuando la respuesta es buena pero se queda corta de ser una buena respuesta, los moderadores pueden empujarte para que mejores algunas secciones o proveas más información sobre el tema

Sobre por qué las respuestas/buena información en comentarios es una mala idea, revisa [esta publicación por Robert Cartaino](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/a/218/109) (adaptado):

> Los comentarios fueron diseñados para simplemente preguntar por clarificaciones sobre la pregunta original. Los comentarios son un mecanismo ligero tal que colocar información *útil* en ellos puede ser en realidad algo peligroso:
>
> - Los comentarios no pueden ser investigados (votados para que se corrijan).
> - La información en los comentarios no se puede editar por la comunidad.
> - Los comentarios no se pueden buscar fácilmente. Cuando los usuarios buscan por tus publicaciones, es mucho menos probable que la encuentren en comentarios.
> - Cuando los usuarios ven que una respuesta ha sido respondida en comentarios, ellos tienden a contribuir menos con respuestas apropiadas.
> - Las preguntas con respuestas basadas en comentarios permanecen marcadas por el sistema como "sin responder", lo cual no augura nada bueno para la comunidad.
>
> Cuando alguien formula una pregunta, se supone que los miembros de la comunidad pueden proponer respuestas. Otros votan esas respuestas y así, rápidamente, las respuestas con más votos van a la cima. No tienes que leer una larga discusión para encontrar la mejor respuesta. **Las respuestas-como-comentarios rompen esa estructura por completo.**
>
> Las discusiones en comentarios no son mejores que un sistema de anuncios en Internet. Cada vez que un nuevo usuario llega, tienen que leer la publicación inicial, luego todo el ruido en los comentarios para entender la historia completa. Terminas con fragmentos valiosos de la solución esparcidos entre un montón de ruido y conversación. Esa es una condición que nosotros trabajamos arduamente para prevenir en los sitios:: [**El Salón de Chat/Problema del Foro**](http://scobleizer.com/2009/11/02/the-chat-roomforum-problem-an-apology-to-technosailor/).

#### ¡De acuerdo, genial! ¿Entonces cuándo debería usar el chat?

Si necesitas tener discusiones extendidas con el OP para clarificar cosas o trabajar en una solución, entonces deberías considerar usar el chat en lugar de comentarios de ida y vuelta. Así, podrán hablar todo lo que gusten y dejar la pregunta libre de desorden. También pueden trabajar de forma colaborativa en una respuesta antes de escribirla.

El chat es un ambiente informal donde se permiten muchas cosas y la única moderación hecha es para spam y contenido ofensivo. Puedes discutir preguntas fuera del tema, finales alternativos para la trilogía de La Guerra de las Galaxias o intercambiar cumplidos.

Espero que esta pequeña guía ayude a aclarar algunas de las confusiones que hay sobre este tema.