# ¿Qué se debe hacer con las respuestas que contengan enlaces?

Tags: discusión

Mientras revisaba preguntas en Stack Overflow en Español, me encontré con esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/30209/78).

El contenido de la respuesta es básicamente un *intento** de recomendación de un sofwtare tercero.

En mi opinión, esta respuesta no responde a la pregunta del OP.

En anteriores oportunidades he recibido el siguiente comentario de parte de otros moderadores en Stack Overflow *en inglés*:

Ejemplo:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40241626/4092887)

Yo he optado por "en lugar de votar negativo", darle la oportunidad al usuario para que edite su respuesta al dejar un [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30187/mostrar-en-un-pdf-solo-lo-que-se-muestre-en-una-tabla/30209#comment49092_30209) *con una estructura similar al ejemplo anterior.*

Este tipo de respuestas en el sitio en inglés no son del todo aceptadas.

Mi pregunta es: ¿qué se debería hacer en estos casos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto se explica en la pregunta/respuesta [¿Qué es una respuesta aceptable?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/958/227), específicamente es el caso #12:

> Tipo de respuesta: Mira aquí: [enlace externo]
>   ¿Qué hacer?: Necesita muchas mejoras. No se considera de calidad para este sitio
>   Acción correctiva: La respuesta debe ser mejorada como se describe sino será borrada. Votar en contra si el enlace es tangencial a la pregunta. Escribir una nueva respuesta detallada y luego reportar como NeuR. También reportar si el enlace está roto.
>   ¿Por qué? "recuerda que las respuestas que dejas no son solo para el OP, sino prácticamente para cualquiera que visita esa página. Si no tienes la voluntad de hacerlo, entonces es una buena idea no publicar ese enlace"

Answer (score 2):

En realidad depende mucho del tipo de pregunta que se haga y de las posibles respuestas que se puedan dar.

Muchas veces es mucho más intuitivo y mejor para el OP (a mí personalmente me ha pasado algunas veces) que le proporcionen un link a una página oficial o al apartado de la documentación oficial que hace referencia a su problema, a que le proporcionen un código que muchas veces es copy-paste. Siempre que esté acompañado de una descripción, aunque sea breve.

Entiendo que cuando te ponen el mensaje en Stackoverflow en inglés (yo también lo he visto algunas veces) es porque estás haciendo referencia a algún link que puede llegar a expirar o caerse, como por ejemplo blogs o páginas de terceros. En cambio, y es pura opinión personal, pienso que si es algún link de alguna documentación oficial es mucho más difícil que se caiga, expire, etc...

Esto no quita que siempre es mucho mejor (no cabe duda) de añadir un pequeño ejemplo junto con el link referente a la documentación oficial para que si el link por algún casual ya no hiciera referencia a ninguna página, esa respuesta no sea totalmente inválida.

En este caso concreto, creo que más que una respuesta debería ser un comentario ya que no proporciona ninguna descripción y simplemente hace una referencia a un link como diciendo "toma, cogelo, apañatelas tu solo".

**¿Qué suele pasar con este tipo de respuestas?**

Normalmente, y por la experiencia que tengo en Stackoverflow en inglés, tal y como dices no suelen ser bien aceptadas por la comunidad por lo que acaban teniendo un montón de votos negativos y finalmente se acaban borrando.

**¿Qué se debería hacer en estos casos?**

Yo personalmente siempre hago lo mismo que tú, aviso al que responde que sería mejor añadir algo más de información por si el link en algún momento dejara de funcionar.

Si proporcionas un link, aunque no lleve código, si lleva una descripción (por pequeña que sea) no se va a quedar totalmente invalidada en caso de que el link se rompa.

Yo la verdad que después de avisar me quedo con la conciencia tranquila. Es cuestión de cada uno el tipo de respuestas que quiere dar y el que responde será libre totalmente de dejarla como está o mejorarla.

También me gusta pensar que como normalmente el tipo de usuarios que realizan estas respuestas tienen baja reputación, al ser nuevos ponen respuestas que deberían ser comentarios al no tener reputación suficiente (yo también lo hice cuando empecé y también me gustó que me corrigieran).

Por lo tanto, yo lo que hago es avisar al que ha puesto la respuesta y esperar a ver si la cambia. Si pasa mucho tiempo y la respuesta sigue igual, depende de cómo esté formulada la pregunta (en mi opinión, si la pregunta también es muy pobre no se merece respuestas elaboradas), voto para eliminar dicha respuesta.