# ¿Es o no es una respuesta aceptable?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, respuesta-propia

En [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31301/falla-funci%C3%B3n-system-math-round2429402-5-de-net-y-redondea-hacia-abajo-con-242/), OP pide que alguien le explique ***por qué*** su código no funciona como él esperaba. Por supuesta, OP recibe varias excelentes respuestas dándole buenas explicaciones del ***por qué***, y de hecho OP marca una de ellas como la respuesta aceptada.

Pero luego, OP agregó una [*"respuesta"*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/31558/18951) propia para indicar la manera cómo usó la información de las demás respuestas para modificar su código de la manera como él quería.

Sin embargo, al menos en mi opinión, su [*"respuesta"*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/31558/18951) no intenta contestar la pregunta planteada. Me parece mas como si estuviera dejando un comentario para ponernos al tanto de cómo las demás respuestas le beneficiaron personalmente.

Mi pregunta es: **¿es o no es una respuesta aceptable?**

Yo lo reporté como *no es una respuesta*, pero quedó en disputa. Alguien me pudiera ayudar a entender, para referencia futura, por qué en este caso la respuesta pudiera considerarse aceptable?

**Edición**

Puesto de otra manera, si la pregunta fuera:

> ¿Por qué no funciona correctamente mi Honda Civic?

Y la respuesta es:

> Al final, decidí cambiar mi vehículo para un Toyota Camry ya que es mejor en mi situación actual y también por las siguientes razones, etc...

¿Se considera una respuesta aceptable?

**Nota adicional**

Por supuesto, previamente leí el excelente hilo [¿Qué es una respuesta aceptable?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/958/qu%C3%A9-es-una-respuesta-aceptable). Pero no veo dónde encaja este caso en los ejemplos citados, por lo que hago esta pregunta.

Comment: Realmente, yo no la consideraría una respuesta "aceptable". Básicamente porque es igual a la que ha establecido @Byron unas respuestas más arriba. Para más inri, no es la misma respuesta que el OP ha elegido como respuesta aceptada, lo que puede confundir todavía más a los usuarios que se pasen por la pregunta en un futuro. La verdad que en este caso no puedo hablar porque no se nada de C# pero si entendiera del tema, eliminaría la respuesta y le pediría al OP que seleccionara como aceptada la respuesta que realmente le ha ayudado a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 2):

En mi opinión, es una respuesta aceptable, fuera de si tiene errores técnicos (no trabajo con C#). No tiene la misma calidad que las demás respuestas, pero tiene lo mínimo para que sea aceptable: el código que resuelve el problema y una explicación concisa (por no decir muy breve) de por qué lo resuelve.

En casos como este, lo que yo suelo hacer: no votar, que sea una respuesta aceptable no significa que sea de ayuda para el sitio. Y dependiendo si es que puede tener errores técnicos (definiciones, código que no compila, etc) u otros problemas, pondría un comentario y quizás (muy probable que) vote en negativo.

Comment: Pero, estamos de acuerdo que no contesta la pregunta, no?

Comment: @sstan no conozco mucho de C# así que no opino al respecto. Si te parece que la respuesta no aporta al sitio, puedes votarle negativo.