# Responder a tu pregunta con una respuesta poco acertada

Tags: discusión, respuesta-propia

Hace unos días hice la pregunta [Tipo de dato para recibir archivo en Asp.net (C# ) enviado desde JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42358/tipo-de-dato-para-recibir-archivo-en-asp-net-c-enviado-desde-javascript).
La pregunta no está mal, pero debido a los requerimientos con los que yo necesitaba trabajar, no hay forma de hacer lo preguntado.

Quisiera añadir una respuesta diciendo que, con las indicaciones dadas, no se puede realizar lo que quiero, que se tienen que cambiar.

¿Es esto correcto? En tal caso, ¿cómo debería responder? ¿O por el contrario es mejor que la pregunta quede abierta?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Es correcto y es lo recomendado. Puedes publicar una respuesta con una plantilla como sigue:

> "Bajo los requerimientos solicitados, actualmente no es posible realizarlo. Se puede hacer algo similar o un workaround con *foo*, *bar* así (... continúa la explicación)."

Recuerda que la respuesta que brindes debe cumplir con los estándares de las publicaciones del sitio. Te recomiendo revisar [¿Qué es una respuesta aceptable?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/958/227)