# ¿Las respuestas tipo "yo haría esto" son válidas?

Tags: discusión, respuesta

En la pregunta [¿Como obtener la cantidad de veces que se repite un valor en un array?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/96339/83) yo indiqué a un usuario en un comentario cómo resolvería el problema que tiene. Fue decírselo a grandes rasgos, sin incluir código, puesto que yo no sé del lenguaje en cuestión. La respuesta que está aceptada hizo prácticamente lo que yo dije, pero con el código correspondiente.

No estoy difamando ni menospreciando su respuesta, pero, si yo hubiera puesto mis comentarios a modo de respuesta, ¿se consideraría como una respuesta válida?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Qué es una respuesta aceptable?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/958/qu%c3%a9-es-una-respuesta-aceptable) "Los comentarios fueron diseñados para simplemente preguntar por clarificaciones sobre la pregunta original."

Comment: no creo que sea duplicada, puesto que en ninguno de los casos descritos, veo relación alguna con lo que yo pregunté, pero gracias por pasarte a mi pregunta :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí es válido mencionar en una respuesta lo que el autor de la misma haría, de hecho, se podría decir que las respuestas que incluyen código son del tipo "yo haría esto".

Comment: siento disentir.. pero en las de codigo si.. en las de disenio.. mmm... no hay un solo tipo de diseno y no habria una respuesta correcta.. en las de codigo podriamos decir que hay una forma de hacerlo mas aceptada que las otras? igual +1

Comment: entonces creo que a la proxima en vez de decirle que es lo que yo haría, lo pondré como respuesta, esperando que no caiga en la maldad de los -1, gracias :D

Comment: @gbianchi sé que no aplica en todas las respuestas, pero sólo preguntaba si una respuesta de ese tipo sería considerada como mala ^^

Answer (score 2):

> Si yo hubiera puesto mis comentarios a modo de respuesta, ¿se
>   consideraría como una respuesta válida?

Son válidas **siempre y cuando respondan a la pregunta del OP**, pero, como todo contenido de Stack Overflow **debe contar con una calidad aceptable**<sup>1</sup>.

Ver **[¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**.

---

<sup>1</sup> Evitando así que la respuesta sea catalogada como "no es una respuesta" o "muy baja calidad".

Answer (score 0):

cuando se utiliza el ***“yo haría esto”*** en las respuestas generalmente son:

- Preguntas muy abiertas
- Falta de redaccion
- Falta de interpretacion

Debido a esto, no es muy comun que la comunidad las acepte salvo aquellas preguntas muy particulares que la solucion no se encuentra.

Answer (score 0):

Considero que una pregunta en la que se contesta usando "**yo haría esto**" es valida porque el que contesta puede saber que la solución puede venir por diferentes caminos y según su preferencia, experiencia pues esta dando la respuesta que el considera "mejor" pero sabe que no es la única verdad verdadera