# ¿Cómo uso correctamente el reporte "No es una respuesta"?

Tags: soporte, faq, respuesta, reportes

<sub>Esta es una traducción de la versión inglesa en Meta.SE [How do I properly use the "Not an Answer" flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185073/209901)</sub>

- ¿Qué es el reporte "No es una respuesta" y cuál es su cometido?
- ¿Cuándo debería usar este reporte?
- ¿Cuando *no* debería usar este reporte?
- Pero aún no estoy seguro si lo estoy usando bien...
- La respuesta claramente cumple las condiciones para el reporte, ¡pero así y todo fue rechazado!

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](/q/1378/)

**Véase también**
[¿Qué es una respuesta aceptable?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/958/83)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Esta respuesta adicional está tomada de [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/579895))

--

## Qué reportar

Se deben marcar las cosas publicadas como respuestas que no intentan responder a la pregunta. Los ejemplos son:

#### Agradecer a otros usuarios

> ¡Grasias! Tenía el mismo poblema y esta pajina me ayudo mucho.

#### Haciendo una nueva pregunta

> Entonces, ¿cómo aplico esto al frobnar cuando me tergiversé el foozbain?

#### Pidiendo clarificaciones

> No lo entiendo; quieres hacer un foo en el bar, pero no incluiste un rastreo. ¿Puedes añadir eso a tu pregunta, por favor?

#### 'Subiendo' la pregunta

> Hombre, tengo exactamente el mismo problema, ¿ya tienes una solución para esto?

Ninguna de estas son respuestas, ni son spam ni son ofensivas. Deberían ser borradas, que es para lo que sirve el reporte de "no es una respuesta". Te sorprendería la frecuencia con la que este tipo de mensajes aparecen.

#### Enlaces a una respuesta

Esencialmente esto:

> [image]

Si no hay nada en la respuesta misma que indique en qué dirección nos están apuntando, no es una respuesta y debe ser borrada.

En otras palabras:

> La respuesta puede ser encontrada aquí: <enlace>

Nótese que esto no es necesariamente lo mismo que "respuesta de sólo enlace" (aunque hay mucho solapamiento). En particular, las respuestas en las que el enlace *sólo* es la respuesta a la pregunta están excluidas y no deben marcarse. Por ejemplo, cuando el texto del enlace es una función/API y el objetivo del enlace es la documentación asociada. Otro ejemplo se puede encontrar [aquí](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355035/first-post-review-audit-thought-the-answer-was-link-only-when-a-url-was-the-a/355037#355037).

[Una regla práctica es quitar el marcado](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer): si sigue siendo una respuesta (o un intento de) sin el enlace, entonces es una respuesta y no debe ser marcada.

[image: Imagen]

---

Si encuentras una respuesta especialmente inútil, como una con un enlace *muerto*, es mejor usar el reporte de "requiere atención del moderador" para que puedas *explicar* a los moderadores por qué la publicación debe ser eliminada. No hagas que los moderadores deban adivinar; sé explícito, en lugar de usar un reporte genérico de "no es una respuesta". Haz esto *sólo* si no puedes mejorar la publicación tú mismo y la única solución posible es la eliminación. Ejemplos de formas de arreglar una respuesta de baja calidad de sólo enlace son:

- Editar la información pertinente del enlace. Intenta *resumir* la información en tus propias palabras y [citar las partes relevantes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

  (No copies el código de GitHub Gists o de otras fuentes donde la licencia sea incompatible con nuestra licencia CC BY-SA. Sólo el propietario original del contenido puede otorgar licencias cruzadas, por lo que debe ser el que lo edite. Este es un buen caso para levantar una bandera de moderador personalizada, o para dejar un comentario).
- Reemplazando el enlace con la nueva ubicación de la página o con [una copia archivada](https://archive.org/).
- Dejar un comentario informando al autor de los problemas con la respuesta y pedirle amablemente que los solucione. (Esto es especialmente apropiado para las respuestas antiguas, publicadas por usuarios aún activos, que alguna vez fueron útiles pero que no han envejecido bien).

## Lo que no hay que marcar

**Cualquier publicación que intente responder a la pregunta—aunque sea mal—sigue siendo una respuesta**! No uses el reporte de "no es una respuesta" para las respuestas *equivocadas*. Los moderadores no juzgan la corrección técnica de las respuestas.

Puedes votar en contra de tales respuestas como una señal de que son malas y no útiles, pero son *todavía respuestas*, así que no debes marcarlas.

Comment: ¿Entonces se consideran los casos de "_+¿A donde vas?_ _-Manzanas traigo_"  como respuestas? (El dicho venia a cuento con las imágenes :D)

Comment: @x3kagainstSEbehavior (i got that reference) por supuesto que no. La respuesta  debe tener relacion con la pregunta. Pero si se está intentando responder genuinamente, aunque la respuesta sea horrible, no se debe marcar como "no es una respuesta".