# Auto-respuesta DEMASIADO completa?

Tags: discusión

En esta pregunta:

[C++ - Declarar múltiples variables en un bucle y utilizarlas para realizar cálculos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/333440/19610)

El autor, además de marcar como *aceptada* la única respuesta que había, [se ha molestado en incluir una auto-respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/333531/19610), detallando todos los pasos a seguir y explicando con detalle su código.

Personalmente, opino que esto **no tiene cabida en el sitio**, salvo, tal vez, en el caso de ser wiki de comunidad ... pero en ese supuesto, la respuesta estaría orientada a casos genéricos, mientras que la referida publicación se limita a un caso concreto, en un contexto concreto, de un usuario concreto.

No es que sea habitual ... al menos, en las etiquetas en las que me muevo, es la primera vez que lo veo.

¿ Que se hace con esta respuesta ? ¿ Positivo ? ¿ Negativo ? ¿ *Flagelar* ?

<sub>**Nota:** De momento, [le he dejado un comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/333440/c-declarar-m%C3%BAltiples-variables-en-un-bucle-y-utilizarlas-para-realizar-c%C3%A1lcu#comment605086_333531) con un enlace a esta misma pregunta.</sub>

#### Edito

...Ummmm ... un negativo. Entiendo que alguien no está de acuerdo y opina que **SI** tienen cabida en el sitio. Para esos *alguienes* ... ¿ como puntuamos esas respuestas ? ¿ Tienen mas mérito que el autor de la respuesta *aceptada* que ayudo al OP ? ¿ Las dejamos estar sin más, sin puntuar ? ¿ Depende de *quién la tiene mas grande* ?

Recordemos que la puntuación depende (o *debería depender*) de la calidad técnica de la respuesta. ¿ Una respuesta auto-publicada que dependió de otras para realizarse, tiene **mas calidad técnica** que las respuestas en las que se basó ?

Comment: No entiendo lo de _..Ummmm ... un negativo_. ¿A qué negativo te refieres?

Comment: Al negativo de esta misma pregunta: Sin un comentario aclaratorio, sobreentiendo que ese -1 indica que al menos 1 usuario no está de acuerdo conmigo.

Comment: Ah, resultaba confuso. En general, es bueno que las preguntas se puedan leer de una tacada y sin cortes temporales: cosas como _edito_, _actualización_ y referencias temporales complican el objetivo

Comment: Mi voto y apoyo están contigo Trauma

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La respuesta del OP es un poco extraña, mas que una respuesta parece que quería compartir su código final explicándolo como un *tutorial*.

> Después de mucha desesperación y fallo y ensayo, conseguí terminar el
>   código, siguiendo el consejo de @Akamai, y el resultado es el
>   siguiente: ...

Como comentas y estoy de acuerdo **esta** respuesta no tiene cabida en el sitio. Creo que si el OP quiere compartir su código final en forma de tutorial debería de hacerlo fuera del sitio (un blog, otra web enfocada a ello...) y enlazarla como comentario a su pregunta por si a alguien le interesa.

Respecto a que se puede hacer, es algo mas complicado... Pero supongo que votar negativo si crees que la respuesta no va con el sitio. Para saber si se debería de reportar habría que analizar la respuesta en base a este hilo. [¿Cómo uso correctamente el reporte “No es una respuesta”?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4604/128699)

> **Cualquier publicación que intente responder a la pregunta—aunque sea
>   mal—sigue siendo una respuesta!**

---

> ¿Una respuesta auto-publicada que dependió de otras para realizarse,
>   tiene mas calidad técnica que las respuestas en las que se basó?

<sub><sup>Esto es general, no es pensando en este caso en concreto.</sup></sub>

Una respuesta auto-publicada que dependió de otra **puede** tener mas calidad técnica. La respuesta original quizás iba bien encaminada pero no era completa y quizás después de arreglar tu problema puedes dar una respuesta mucho mas completa o completar la del OP original (depende de si tienes mucho o poco que aportar).

Answer (score 5):

No estoy de acuerdo con [@Trauma](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/19610).

Tengo las siguientes ideas generales:

- Es muy común que el AP publique una respuesta detallada(y específica) de como aplico las otras respuestas a su caso particular.
- Una respuesta es válida si intenta solucionar el problema de la pregunta.
- Seria inválida si fuese un plagio.
- Que una respuesta sea buena no implica que las demás no lo sean.
- Algunas respuestas son detalladas y otras no, algunas respuestas son generales y otras se van al caso particular.
- Una respuesta que se base en otra sigue siendo válida(salvo el caso del plagio) ya que muestra como el AP entendio la solución, por ejemplo hay casos donde el usuario experto da una solución general que muchos principiantes no entienden por lo que la solucion particular hace que cualquier usuario pueda entender.
- Hay respuestas que tienen como unico objetivo mostrar la aplicación práctica de otras soluciones, es decir traducir la explicación teorica de una respuesta a código.

*¿ Que se hace con esta respuesta ? ¿ Positivo ? ¿ Negativo ? ¿ Flagelar ?*

Pues depende de cada usuario, si para ti la respuesta es buena entonces dale tu UV, sino entonces dale tu DV. El *flag*(supongo que quiso escribir *flagear*) lo veo innecesario en este caso.

Comment: Entonces ... ¿ Puedo publicar, en todas las preguntas que he hecho, un resumen final de como resolví el problema, detallando todos los pasos ? Seguramente un 90% de esas publicaciones serán cosas **sin relación con la pregunta original**, pero relevantes para el problema.

Comment: @Trauma Hay que diferenciar que es el problema y que es la pregunta. El problema es una idea muy amplia que el AP suele saber que es y la pregunta suele ser el resumen del problema ya que se señala algo muy específico que puede ser errado inicialmente ya que por obvias razones el OP no puede entender el problema

Comment: @Trauma Como señale: si consideras que no es adecuado para el sitio dale tu DV.

Comment: No lo tengo claro ... de ahí esta pregunta. De momento parece que va ganando el si.

Answer (score 3):

Si el AP ha publicado una respuesta debe limitar su respuesta a responder la pregunta. Está bien que incluya algún comentario al margen pero de ninguna manera debería incluir explicaciones que no están relacionadas directamente con la pregunta.

Recordemos que en las preguntas se sugiere incluir un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), y para las respuestas, en mi opinión, debe aplicarse el mismo criterio, el código de la respuesta, incluyendo las explicaciones, deberían ser mínimo, completo y verificable.

En cuanto a qué se debe hacer cuando hacer en casos como este, pues empezaría por no llamarles "demasiado completa", luego sería bueno que se le dejaran comentarios sugeriéndole al AP/AR como hacer de su respuesta una buena respuesta. El darle un voto ya sea negativo o positivo debe quedar a criterio de los que les interese el tema de la pregunta/respuesta.

Comment: Lo del título fue, digamos, cuestión de *marketing*. Por otra parte, tu opinión concuerda totalmente con la mia (aunque te has explicado mejor). Pero parece ser que la comunidad no comparte nuestro punto de vista :-(